# Ruby UUID and uniqueness, for an ID

Tags: ruby, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I need a 6 character alphanumeric ID for use in my rails app, which will be presented to users of the system and must be unique among all the object instances in my system. I don't expect more than a few thousand object instances, so 6 characters is far more than I really need.

At this point I'm using the UUIDTools gem in my Rails app to generate a uuid. Which of the UUIDTools generation methods should I use, and which end of the resulting uuid should I take the 6 characters from, to guarantee uniqueness?

for example, if I generate `ef1cf087-95c9-4868-bd95-cea950a52b58`, would I want to use `ef1cf0` from the front of it, or `a52b58` from the back end?

... as a side note / question: am i going about this wrong? is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way. UUID is considered unique because it is very long and it is practically impossible to generate same UUIDs. If you trim it to 6 chars then you drammatically increase possiblility of duplicate. You have to use either incrementing id or full UUID.

Only deterministic generation (`id(x + 1) = id(x) + 1`) can guarantee uniqueness. UUID doesn't **guarantee it** and 6 chars guarantee it even less.

Other option is to create ID generation service, it will have single method `getNewId` and will keep knowledge that will be enought to provide unique ids. (Simplest case - counter)

Comment: incrementing ID and full UUID are not options. provide me an option to generate a 6 digit alphanumeric id that is unique.

Comment: @Derick Bailey there are none. you can achieve uniqueness either statistically (UUID case) or by sharing of knowledge of previously generated ids (increment). Random 6 chars fall in neither category.

Comment: d'oh! sorry... accidental click of the downvote, and it won't let me undo it... says vote is locked unless answer is edited.

Comment: @Derick Bailey I added some info, so that you can remove downvote and I hope that it is also useful

Comment: odd.. refresh page and now it lets me undo the downvote. anyways... what are the chances that grabbing 6 characters would make it not unique?

Comment: You could always base-36 encode (0-9a-z) an incremented integer id.  That will give you an alpha-numeric identifier, but guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: @Derick Bailey I wrote test app that measures amount of generations until you get same ids. It takes less then 10k iterations to have a collision. One time it took 800 iterations. This is unacceptable.

Comment: @dunedain289 I understood that the problem is not about format, but about centralized generation.

Comment: @Andrey He mentioned that this is a Rails app, so I made the assumption that the objects in question are ActiveRecord model objects.  If they're not, I have no idea how he's saving and restoring them anyways, so it seems like a harder problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you say that incrementing the ID isn't an option, is that because you don't want users to see the scheme you're using, or because the generation must be stateless (i.e., you can't keep track of all IDs you've generated)?

If it's the former, then you can generate an ID, check to see if you've already used it, and if so, generate another new ID.  (Seems pretty obvious so sorry if I'm on the wrong track.)  You could do something like this:

```
while id = rand(2**256).to_s(36)[0..5] 
   break unless Ids.exists?(id)
end
```

where `Ids.exists?(id)` is the does-this-already-exist method.

Comment: oh boy will this algorithm have interesting O-notation figures!

Comment: Right, it's the cost of generating the key (constant) plus the cost of checking for a collision (if the table's in memory, depends on the hash function). Given that Derick said he's only generating a few thousand keys, collisions are very unlikely.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer even if it's distasteful.